# How to save changes in ListPicker Wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

In the `ListPicker` in my Windows Phone Application there is a List of items which a user can select one or more items and view those selected items. 
Until this point everything goes fine after this point I want to save the selected items on the same page. Now what happens when I close the application and starts it again there is no selected items saved. So my question is how can I save the changes made by the user? I don't want to save them in a separate file in the isolated storage actually. Thanks in advance.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Border x:Name="Border"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <UserControl x:Name="UserControl">
        <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock x:Name="MultipleSelectionModeSummary" Margin="8 8 0 8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
             <Canvas x:Name="ItemsPresenterHost" MinHeight="46">
                 <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter">
                     <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                         <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                     </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                 </ItemsPresenter>
             </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>         
    </UserControl>
</Border>
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Print in colors"
                            SelectionMode="Multiple"
                            FullModeHeader="Colors"
                            CacheMode="BitMapCache"
                            x:Name="PrintInColors" 
        Template="{StaticResource ListPickerControlTemplate1}">
            <sys:String>Cyan</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Magenta</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Yellow</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Black</sys:String>
            <sys:String>White</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Blue</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Orange</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Gray</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Silver</sys:String>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Here is the CS code:

```
private string Summarize(System.Collections.IList items)
{
    string str = "";
    if (null != items)
    {
        if (items.Contains("Cyan"))
        {
            str += "Cyan";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Magenta"))
        {
            str += "Mangeta";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Yellow"))
        {
            str += "Yellow";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Black"))
        {
            str += "Black";
        }
        if (items.Contains("White"))
        {
            str += "White";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Blue"))
        {
            str += "Blue";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Orange"))
        {
            str += "Orange";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Gray"))
        {
            str += "Gray";
        }
        if (items.Contains("Silver"))
        {
            str += "Silver";
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please rethink. You need persistent storage to achieve that. Your application is installed and never get changed. I mean, all changes user made are in memory (RAM) and it will be unloaded/removed soon after the application closed.

Isolated storage is the most commonly used persistent storage for this purpose. And it is relatively simple as far as I can see (compared to saving to local or online database), so you really should consider saving the data to isolated storage.

Comment: I think your right I should change my strategy. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achiveing this but this one is the most native to windows phone.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Best case for your app is using isolated storage.I think it is the most simplest and best way to do it.follow the link if you need more about isolated storage..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx